# How to combine Date object with float Vector

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading two data frames from two separate csvs and trying to combine them in a single data frame.Both df1 & df2 should be combined row by row.df1 contains floating numbers and 
df2 is a date.

```
df1=pd.read_csv("Weights.csv")
print(df1.head(5))
df2=pd.read_csv("Date.csv")
print(df2.head(5))


      0     1    2    3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10    11   12  
0  0.06  0.06 -0.0 -0.0  0.11  0.06  0.37  0.01  0.05  0.10 -0.00  0.01  0.0   
1  0.09  0.05 -0.0 -0.0  0.12  0.05  0.36  0.00  0.05  0.08  0.00  0.00 -0.0   
2  0.14  0.07 -0.0  0.0  0.13  0.04  0.33  0.01  0.04  0.05  0.00  0.00  0.0   
3  0.13  0.07  0.0 -0.0  0.12  0.06  0.34  0.01  0.05  0.04  0.01  0.00 -0.0   
4  0.11  0.08  0.0  0.0  0.08  0.10  0.35  0.05  0.05  0.06  0.02  0.00  0.0 

            0
0  2010-12-29
1  2011-01-05
2  2011-01-12
3  2011-01-19
4  2011-01-26
```

I am facing problem using pd.concat in pandas.

Comment: So what _did_ happen when you tried `pd.concat`?

Comment: I am getting the dates but Nans for other columns. like:                                     
2010-12-29 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN